# Combining two conditions in one filter expression

Tags: qgis, query, filter

I have a Shapefile that shows local municipalities and ward boundaries for South Africa. I would like to filter this layer to only show the wards I am interested in.

For example, my first query finds two wards in a local municipality:

```sql
"LocalMun_1" = 'Alfred Duma' AND "WardNumber" IN ('28', '17')
```

I would now like to add two more wards from a different local municipality:

```sql
"LocalMun_1" = 'Mpofana' AND "WardNumber" IN ('2', '4')
```

How would I combine the two queries into the same filter expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `OR` to assemble the two conditions:

```sql
("LocalMun_1" = 'Alfred Duma' AND "WardNumber" IN ('28', '17')) OR ("LocalMun_1" = 'Mpofana' AND "WardNumber" IN ('2', '4'))
```

In logic operators, `OR` stands for `AND & OR`, if the first expression is `True`, it adds the second one if `True`.

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple! I always thought OR meant one or the other. Thanks for your answer, worked like a charm.

Comment: Comment added in my answer.